# jQuery AJAX returning error 0 while communicating with ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm learning ASP.NET and I wanted to whip up a simple site that uses ajax to just get a string back from the server.

When I run the ajax request it displays `An error occured: 0 error`

Here's what I have so far

The controller for the index page with the ajax request on it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

The Controller for the ajax request:

```
public class AjaxTestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult AjaxAction()
    {
        return Content(@"Success!");
    }
}
```

the jQuery from the index page:

```
$( "#submit_button" ).click(function( event ) 
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:49636/AjaxTest/AjaxAction",
        data: "{}",
        success:function(result){
            alert( "Response: " + result );
        },
        error:function(xhr){
            alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }});
});
```

When I go to `http://localhost:49636/AjaxTest/AjaxAction` in my browser it displays `Success!` as expected.

Other questions about error 0 say it could have something to do with trying to access a different domain, but I'm not sure that applies here. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your type to "GET" rather than "POST"?

Comment: That is I changed the jquery call. Is there something I have to change on the .net side?

Answer (score 0):

You could also add the `[HttpPost]`-Flag to the `AjaxAction`.